# How do I quote square brackets in Ansible variable value for regexp parameter?

Tags: regular-expression, quoting, ansible

I use the `ansible.builtin.lineinfile` module to modify a PHP-FPM pool configuration file. How should I quote the square brackets (annot.: or other special characters) in a value of a variable for the regexp parameter?

Without quoting the square brackets are interpreted as bracket expression - a list of characters to be matching. Without Ansible I would use sed to add a backslash.

The following example is for a Debian default pool conf file.

```yaml
- name: Change PHP-FPM pool parameters
  become: true
  ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
    path: "/etc/php/{{ php_fpm_version }}/fpm/pool.d/www.conf"
    regexp: "^;?{{ item.para }} ="
    line: '{{ item.para }} = {{ item.value }}'
  loop: "{{ php_fpm_pool_parameters }}"
  vars:
    php_fpm_pool_parameters:
    - para: 'pm.max_spare_servers'
      value: '7'
    - para: 'pm.max_requests'
      value: '500'
    - para: 'env[PATH]'
      value: '/usr/bin:/bin'
    - para: 'php_admin_value[memory_limit]'
      value: '4096M'
    - para: 'php_admin_value[max_input_time]'
      value: '600'
```

Comment: Since you are writing already in `line: '{{ item.para }}'` you can also write in `regexp: "^;?{{ item.para }} ="`. There should be no need for an other syntax. Documentation: [Referencing nested variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#referencing-nested-variables).

Comment: Sure, but this does not solve the problem. The square brackets in the three last list items are interpreted as "bracket expression", which means as P, A, T or H in the first case.

Comment: Because of the comment "_Sure_" and then the opposite "_does not solve the problem_", can you provide a more detailed description?

Comment: To avoid misunderstandings, I have changed the line. The `{{ item['para'] }}` was an attempt to solve the problem by avoiding conflicts like described here: [Referencing key:value dictionary variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#referencing-key-value-dictionary-variables)
The problem is that regex is supposed to search for [PATH], including the square bracket, and not P, A, T, or H.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the regex special characters in your string so that they are taken literally. FYI, escaping is not different in ansible than outside (i.e. you add the escape char which is `\`).

Fortunately, there is a [`regex_escape` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#searching-strings-with-regular-expressions) made just for that.

The following (untested) should suit your needs. Note: for extra security I marked the space preceding the `=` sign as optional and extended the regexp to match the entire line.

```yaml
- name: Change PHP-FPM pool parameters
  become: true
  ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
    path: "/etc/php/{{ php_fpm_version }}/fpm/pool.d/www.conf"
    regexp: "^;?{{ item.para | regex_escape }} ?=.*$"
    line: '{{ item.para }} = {{ item.value }}'
  loop: "{{ php_fpm_pool_parameters }}"
  vars:
    php_fpm_pool_parameters:
    - para: 'pm.max_spare_servers'
      value: '7'
    - para: 'pm.max_requests'
      value: '500'
    - para: 'env[PATH]'
      value: '/usr/bin:/bin'
    - para: 'php_admin_value[memory_limit]'
      value: '4096M'
    - para: 'php_admin_value[max_input_time]'
      value: '600'
```